# Relacionar tabelas MySQL e filtrar por data

Tags: mysql

Eu preciso de só um valor final, o valor de comissão referente aos produtos com comissão extra em um intervalo de datas e de um vendedor especifico, as informações estão em 3 tabelas no BD:

Abaixo é a tabela 'produtos_comissao_extra', a coluna 'Data_abertura' mostra quando o produto começou a ter comissão extra, e 'Data_fechamento' quando deixou de ter, a coluna valor é quanto de comissão se ganha por unidade vendida (cada vez que se coloca comissão extra em um produto ele cria um novo registro ao invés de alterar o antigo, para poder ter um histórico)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a Itens_venda, ela mostra os produtos das vendas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E essa é a de vendas (o Id do funcionário e a data da venda ficam aqui)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até agora o código que eu escrevi com a ajuda foi o seguinte:

```
SELECT itens_venda.Id_produto, Quantidade, Valor, Id_funcionario, data_venda
FROM genius.Itens_venda
JOIN genius.vendas ON itens_venda.Id_venda = vendas.Id 
JOIN produtos_comissao_extra ON produtos_comissao_extra.Id_produto = itens_venda.Id_produto
WHERE data_venda BETWEEN Data_abertura AND ifnull(Data_fechamento,curdate()) AND Id_funcionario = 5
ORDER BY Data_fechamento DESC;
```

O resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É quase o que eu preciso, só falta filtrar por um intervalo de data especifico, por exemplo, quero só do mês 7, mas tem que seguir tudo que já foi escrito no código, só tenho que filtrar o resultado que eu já tenho

Comment: Não tem problema, você pode e deve postar o que você fez. Isso te incentiva a querer resolver a situação. Mostre o código que você fez. Assim terá ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode começa usando o [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) para unir suas tabelas, usar a cláusula [WHERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) para referenciar um campo especifico *(vendedor especifico)* a cláusula [BETWEEN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) para um intervalo de datas *(comissão extra em um intervalo de datas)* e um [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) para otimizar sua consulta caso tenha mais de um resultado.

Aqui tem um pontapé para você começa.

```
   select * from Vendas V
    join Itens_venda IV
    on IV.Id_venda = V.Id 
    join produtos_comissao_extra PC
    on PC.Id_produto = IV.Id_produto
    where V.Id_funcionario = 1
    order by Data_fechamento desc
```

Se você precisa de mais alguma coisa, seria bom editar sua pergunta com mais detalhes.